# Modification of Poisson equation

Tags: terminology, differential-equations

I am looking for properties of the following equation
$$\Delta\phi+(\nabla \phi)^2=4\pi\rho$$
Is there any name of this equation ? (If yes, it would be easier to find some information).

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: What is your notation $\Delta\phi$ represent?

Comment: @Michael: $\Delta\phi\equiv\nabla\cdot\nabla\phi\equiv\nabla^2\phi$ is reasonably common notation.